# In multi-button form how to click button corresponding to active textbox on Enter keypress

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a jsp which contains multiple text boxes and buttons in a single form.On pressing Enter key I want to click submit button which comes immediately after the text box in which I am typing.

```
<body>
<form action="main.jsp" method="GET">  // form with multiple buttons of same type
<li>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"></li>
<li>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /></li>
<<li class="buttonCode"><div><input type="button" value="Submit" /></div></li>
<li>First I Name: <input type="text" name="first_name1"></li>
<li>Last I Name: <input type="text" name="last_name1" /></li>
<li class="buttonCode" ><div><input type="button" value="Submit" /></div></li>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') { //jquery normalizes the keycode 

            event.preventDefault(); //avoids default action
            $(this).find('input[type=submit]').trigger('click');
            // or $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace input type `button` to `submit`

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

it will submit form either on submit button press or enter press